# Get a reference in "for each" java

Tags: java, foreach, reference

I have this code:

```
ArrayList<MyClass> MyArrayList = new ArrayList<MyClass>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    MyClass AuxObject = new Myclass(); // Generates an object whit random properties;
    MyArrayList.add(AuxObject);
}

/*

At this point lets suposse we have the list like this

Obj1
obj2
obj3
obj4
obj5
obj6
obj7
obj8
obj9
obj10

*/


MyClass MyAuxObject = null;

for(MyClass NObject: MyArrayList){
    if(NObject.SomeBoolean == true){
       MyAuxObject = NObject; // is valid?
   break;
   }
}
```

My question is "MyAuxObject" will be a reference to some object on my list or gona be null?
Can i use "Nobject" to get a reference to an object on the list?

Comment: Well, it will not be null if at least one element in the list matches the `if` condition

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on what are you trying to obtain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code

```
for(MyClass NObject: MyArrayList){
    if(MyObject.SomeBoolean == true){
       MyAuxObject = NObject; // is valid?
   break;
   }
}
```

you are extracting the code to an Object called `NObject` but doing a comparison on `MyObject`

I feel that this is not what you are wanting, otherwise you could just get the first element from the list.

Assuming that this is a typo, then `MyAuxObject` will have the value of the first matching `NObject` and if not matching then it will be `null`.

Comment: u are right, i have a mistake there, gona edit right now. Ty for ur help :D!

Answer (score 2):

Java always uses references for objects.

`MyAuxObject` is a reference to the same object that `NObject` referenced.

(That's assuming that something satisfied the `if` condition. Otherwise, `MyAuxObject` is still `null`.)

Comment: Ty so much thats i want to know.